# How to make a fadeout animation when the mouse leaves?

Tags: css

I have made the fade in animation when the mouse enters a div. But I am not able to make the fade out animation when the mouse leaves. This is my code:

```
<div>abcd: </div>

div::after {
    content: "The Breast Pocket was once used mostly to hold handkerchiefs, but generally has moved on to the functionality to hold pocket squares. Pocket squares are our primary accessory to add and show off a great tie.";
    display: none;
    background:  rgba(23,23,90,0.8);
    color: white;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 10px;
    animation-name: out;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}

div:hover::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 26px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    animation-name: in;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes in
{
 0% { opacity: 0;  }
 100% { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes out
{
 from { opacity: 1; }
 to { opacity: 0; }
}
```

And this is the codepen: https://codepen.io/boidurja-talukdar/pen/bGvBjrR

Comment: Do you want there to be a space left for that info or do you want it to appear over anything that comes after it or do you want it to push down anything that comes after it on hover?

Comment: This is the website link: https://brooksbingham.com/content/15-suit-jacket-pockets. This is how I want.

Comment: Ok, so the info is to come on top without moving anything else.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 2):

did you try this code ?  i have some changed on css code.

```css
div::after {
        content: "The Breast Pocket was once used mostly to hold handkerchiefs, but generally has moved on to the functionality to hold pocket squares. Pocket squares are our primary accessory to add and show off a great tie.";
        background:  rgba(23,23,90,0.8);
        color: #fff;
        padding: 15px;
        border: 1px solid grey;
        border-radius: 10px;  
        position: absolute;
        margin-right: 26px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 1s;
}

div:hover::after {
        opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>abcd: </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use transition rather than animation the info will automatically fade out on the hover being removed.

A few other things had to alter here. The info is 'there' all the time in an absolutely positioned element but with opacity 0. The margins are set rather than being introduced on the hover. This is because you otherwise will get 'flashing' as the after element moved under the cursor on a hover, the cursor will hover/not hover/hover as the margins are reset if hovered on the left hand side.

```css
div::after {
  content: "The Breast Pocket was once used mostly to hold handkerchiefs, but generally has moved on to the functionality to hold pocket squares. Pocket squares are our primary accessory to add and show off a great tie.";
  background: rgba(23, 23, 90, 0.8);
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-right: 26px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}

div:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>abcd: </div>
```